# How to resolve NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found in micron

Tags: dependency-injection, javabeans, micronaut

I am getting `NonUniqueBeanException: Multiple possible bean candidates found:` for the below Micronaut code:

```
@Context
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RemoteService {
   private final Provider<Session> remoteSessionFactory;
}
```

I have 2 implementations for the Provider

```
@Slf4j
@Prototype
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RemoteSessionFactoryA implements Provider<Session> {
    //some code here
}

@Slf4j
@Prototype
@AllArgsConstructor
public class RemoteSessionFactoryB implements Provider<Session> {
    //some code here
}
```

I have even tried like this but still getting the same error:

```
private final @Named("remoteSessionFactoryA) Provider<Session> remoteSessionFactory;
```

Please suggest how to resolve this.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `Named` annotation should be part of the constructor argument. Since let Lombok generating the constructor there is no way to set the `@Named` annotation by Lombok.

I recommend to write the constructor yourself such as:

```java
@Context
@Slf4j
public class RemoteService {
   private final Provider<Session> remoteSessionFactory;

   public RemoteService(@Named("remoteSessionFactoryA") Provider<Session> remoteSessionFactory) {
       this.remoteSessionFactory = remoteSessionFactory;
   }
}
```

Micronaut can’t inject the bean because the name doesn’t match the naming convention. The Micronaut document states:

> Micronaut is capable of injecting V8Engine in the previous example, because:
> @Named qualifier value (v8) + type being injected simple name (Engine) == (case-insensitive) == The simple name of a bean of type Engine (V8Engine)
> You can also declare @Named at the class level of a bean to explicitly define the name of the bean.

So if you put the names on the source beans Micronaut will pick up the name you defined.

```java
@Slf4j
@Prototype
@AllArgsConstructor
@Named("remoteSessionFactoryA") 
public class RemoteSessionFactoryA implements Provider<Session> {
    //some code here
}

@Slf4j
@Prototype
@AllArgsConstructor
@Named("remoteSessionFactoryB") 
public class RemoteSessionFactoryB implements Provider<Session> {
    //some code here
}
```

Alternatively create qualifier annotations.

```java
@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface FactoryA {
}

@Qualifier
@Retention(RUNTIME)
public @interface FactoryB {
}
```

and then inject it like this

```java
@Context
@Slf4j
public class RemoteService {
   private final Provider<Session> remoteSessionFactory;

   public RemoteService(@FactoryA Provider<Session> remoteSessionFactory) {
       this.remoteSessionFactory = remoteSessionFactory;
   }
}
```

Comment: Still Facing the same issue

Comment: but why the first approach is not working ?

Comment: I think it´s all mentioned in the answer. Have a look at https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#qualifiers too.

Comment: A bit late, but you can ask Lombok to copy the annotation to the generated constructor. You need to add in the `lombok.config` file : `lombok.copyableannotations+=jakarta.inject.Named`